# C sockets listen for ICMP Time Exceeded packets

Tags: c, sockets, udp, icmp

I'm trying to listen for ICMP Time Exceeded packets from nodes for which I don't know the IP address. After looking at some code online I've seen people supplying `NULL` for the last two parameters of `recvfrom()`, so I tried it:

```
if ((recvfrom(recv_sock, icmp_msg, icmp_msg_len, 0, NULL, NULL)) != -1) {
            /* PROCESS THE INFORMATION */
            printf("Packet received\n");
} else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error receiving packet: %s\n", strerror(errno));
}
```

However, when I run it, the program just hangs.

It doesn't surprise me, because the man page says the following:

> If address is not a null pointer and the socket is not connection-oriented, the source address of the message is filled in.

I'm using UDP to send the packets, which means I'm connectionless. Wireshark is picking up the time exceeded replies when I send a packet with the time to live of 1, so how can I get my program to pick them up?